# Wireplumber on Artix OpenRC doesn't detect audio devices unless i run it manually inside the user

Tags: linux, audio, arch-linux, pipewire, openrc

yesterday I was messing with my Artix Linux installation (I'm using OpenRC as the init, KDE Plasma as the DE and SDDM), and i needed to change the audio server from PulseAudio to PipeWire.

I installed it with the following commands:

`yay -S pipewire-openrc pipewire-pulse-openrc wireplumber-openrc pipewire-alsa pipewire-jack gst-plugin-bad plasma-pa`

After installing it I instructed OpenRC to autostart them with:

`rc-update add pipewire default rc-update add pipewire-pulse default rc-update add wireplumber default`

Then I added my users to the pipewire group via

`usermod -aG pipewire <my username>`

After rebooting I noticed how the 3 programs were running under the user pipewire and that my DE wasn't able to detect any audio devices.
If I start wireplumber manually via terminal then Plasma suddenly gains access to all the audio devices connected to my pc.

I wanted to know if it's possible to resolve the problem in some way

P.S. OpenRC doesn't have user services, you can run services as a specific user but the username is hardcoded and running it for multiple users would mean writing multiple service scripts